# Get ID from URL, params is undefined using Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, parameters

Trying to grab the ID param from the URL, however it seems as though I am not defining my params var. Can't see where I am going wrong so maybe someone can help!

Code

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'view-movie',
  templateUrl : './templates/view-movie.tpl.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ViewmovieComponent implements OnInit {

  public movie = {};
  public id = String;

  constructor(params: RouteParams){};

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = params.get('id');
  }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was suppose to be inserting the params.get in the code block following the constructor function like so

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'view-movie',
  templateUrl : './templates/view-movie.tpl.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ViewmovieComponent implements OnInit {

  public movie = {};
  public id = String;

  constructor(params: RouteParams){

    this.id = params.get('id');

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use either this one

```
constructor(params: RouteParams){this.id = params.get('id');}

  ngOnInit() {console.log(this.id);}
```

or this one

```
constructor(private params: RouteParams){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.params.get('id');
    console.log(this.id);
  }
```

because if we initialize something without declare type then we have to access within the constructor but if we are going to access outside of the constructor then it will be must to use `this`

Comment: Your best bet is to subscribe to the ActivatedRoute.queryParams

You can have a look at this for example: https://modewagon.wordpress.com/2017/09/12/access-url-with-params-angular2/